# Print date and day name between 2 dates in Laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am beginner in Laravel and PH{
I have this code:

```
$dateFrom = '2020-01-14';
$dateTo = '2020-02-19';
```

I need show date with day name (in Polish) between this  dates.

I need result in this form:

2020-01-14 - Tuesday (Wtorek)
2020-01-15 - Wednesday (Środa)

How can I make it?

Comment: Since you're using laravel and laravel comes with Carbon check [Carbon localisation](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-localization)

Comment: OK. How print all days beetween this dates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//...
Carbon::setLocale('pl');
$period = CarbonPeriod::create('2020-01-14', '2020-02-19');

// Iterate over the period
foreach ($period as $date) {
    echo '(' . $date->format('l') . ')' . $date->format('Y-m-d');
}
//...
```